# jQuery returns status code 404 instead of 403

Tags: ajax, jquery, coffeescript, xmlhttprequest

I'm having trouble with jquery 2.0.2 and getting it to identify a HTTP 403 status code when calling my API (hosted on the same machine, just like the static web page the call is coming from). From a web page's javascript, I'm doing an $.ajax GET against a /sessions route to check if the user's cookie is currently set, expecting a 403 if no such cookie exists or if it's not valid.

Ajax is being setup ahead of time with the following call:

```
  setupAjax: ->
    $.ajaxSetup(
      dataType: 'json'
      xhrFields:
        withCredentials: true)
```

The API (nginx reverse proxy logs below) correctly returns 403 for an unauthenticated user:

```
127.0.0.1 - - [06/Jul/2013:22:48:25 -0700] "GET /1/sessions HTTP/1.1" 403 33 "https://foo.localhost.com/" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:22.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/22.0"
```

Firefox agrees:

[image]

However when jQuery's xhr error handler is called, the xhr.status code is for some reason always 404, which throws the logic completely off. For example, say I use the CoffeeScript call below, only the 404 handler is ever called, both if I give it a correct route or even a non-existent route (which correctly returns 404 in both server logs and Firefox)

```
  checkSessionCookie: ->
    $.ajax(
      url: "#{@baseUrl}/sessions"
      type: 'GET'
      statusCode:
        403: -> console.log "I'm a 403"
        404: -> console.log "I'm a 404")
```

(dump of xhr object in console):

```
Object { readyState=4, status=404, statusText="error"}
```

What's going on here? Did I misconfigure jQuery or am I misusing it somehow? Is there a trick here?

Comment: What kind of script is this, exactly?  It doesn't look like javascript to me; you should add the correct tag to your question.

Comment: He does mention coffee script in it?

Comment: Check permissions? Rule of thumb for correct permissions:

Folders: 755
Static Content: 644
Dynamic Content: 700

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on some experimentation it seems that Firefox might have been swallowing up CORS exceptions causing the incorrect status. Chrome was always reporting the CORS call which is why I was testing this with Firefox.

Setting CORS headers on the server made Firefox return 403 correctly.